# Web application load testing

Tags: performance, load-testing

Anyone had experience with load testing tools like WAPT Pro? I want to know, when recording those load test script on a web application, shall i include those like Google Analytic tracking request? Or just focus on application itself will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like the tracking requests have nothing to do with your own application.  Whenever possible, you should avoid hitting these during your performance testing and if you are going to, ensure that said vendor is aware of the testing that is going on.

Personally, I try to only send requests to my applications that I'm testing at the moment.  This can sometimes mean accessing data from other parts of the system, I try to keep it to a minimum.  If it seems like a 3rd party application could be a bottle neck, you may want to discuss with your team and the vendor how the requests could be formed and/or executed that would result in better performance.